# Finding the Grandchildren of a node in python bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the text from the span elements within the empty span element and display them in python. I am using bs4 and can only seem to get the child of the span element with the class. Any ideas?

```
<span class="css-w8p71j">
    <span>
        <span>-$1.12</span>
        <span>(-0.65%)</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

actual python code

```
#imports
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from requests.api import get

#variables
link = 'HELP'
url = 'https://robinhood.com/stocks/'
runAgain = 'True'

#functions
def select():
    global link
    link = input('Input the stock ticker symbol or cmd for a list of commands: ').upper()
    print(link)
    if(link == 'HELP'):
        print('Help: use a browser to see a stocks ticker symbol, for instance AAPL for Apple. Do list in input field to see list of stock ticker symbols.')
        return
    elif(link == 'LIST'):
        print('List:\nAAPL:\tApple\nSPY:\tS&P 500 ETF\nTSLA:\tTesla\nAMC:\tAMC Entertainment\nF:\tFord Motor\nSNDL:\tSundial Growers\nMSFT:\tMicrosoft\nAMZN:\tAmazon\nDIS:\tDisney\nNIO:\tNIO')
        return
    elif(link == 'CMD'):
        print('help: gives information on how to input a stock via ticker symbol\nlist: gives a list of a few major stocks and their ticker symbol\ncmd: yields this information')
        return
    getInfo()

def getInfo():
    global link
    global url
    page = requests.get(url+link)
    if(page.status_code == 404):
        print('Stock not found or available!')
        return
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    value = soup.find("span", class_='up')
    value = (value['aria-label'])
    # change = soup.find('span', class_='css-w8p71j')

   #this is the problem area

    for item in soup.select("*[class^='css-w8p71j']"):        
        child = item.find_all("span")
        print(child) 
        # print(child[1].text)


    print('Current stock price of '+link+': '+str(value)+'\nTotal change today: ')

#main
while(runAgain == 'True'):
    select()
    runAgain = input('Would you like to run again? y/n: ').upper()
    if(runAgain == 'Y'):
        runAgain = 'True'
```

edited to add more python code for background information

Comment: please use an api, scraping the data from pages like this is a waste of time. https://data.nasdaq.com/tools/api

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one `span` main element you can use this:

```
childs = soup.select("*[class^='css-']")[0].find_all("span")[1:]
print(childs[0].text) 
print(childs[1].text)
```

But since this might not be the case and you will most likely have a list of these elements you can iterate on them like this:

```
for item in soup.select("*[class^='css-']"):
   childs = item.find_all("span")[1:] 
   for child in childs:
       if any(str.isdigit(c) for c in child)  
           print(child.text)
```

Comment: I am trying to get the change price and % from this https://robinhood.com/stocks/AAPL what you gave kind of works but yields lots of []

Comment: cant see the spans in this link

Comment: let me edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

Avoid dynamic looking classes, use the existing parent element id as an anchor, then use the relationship of elements, and filtering via nth-child to target the two desired child nodes:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://robinhood.com/stocks/AAPL')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print([s.text for s in soup.select('#sdp-price-chart-price-change div:nth-child(1) span:last-child > span')])
```

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Answer (score 0):

**Note** *Agree with @QHarr about the use of unique structural elements and attributes and that these are definitely preferable to dynamic ones and should determine any selection strategy.*

##### Basic approach

How to get change price and percentage as one string - Select parent `<div>` by `id`, it's  first `<span>` and call `.get_text()` methode:

```
change = soup.select_one('#sdp-price-chart-price-change span').get_text(' / ', strip=True)

Output--> -$1.12 / (-0.65%)
```

##### Alternativ approach

Get both strings separat in list using `css selectors` and in addition `.stripped_strings` generator.

With `select_one()` we select the first child `<span>` in `<div>` with `#sdp-price-chart-price-change` that contains the both "grandchildren" with information we looking for. Calling `.stripped_strings` will generate the stripped strings from every element in our selection - Just wrap it in `list()` or iterate it to work with results:

```
change = list(soup.select_one('#sdp-price-chart-price-change span').stripped_strings)
```

Output is `['-$1.12', '(-0.65%)']` and you can decide using single elements `change[0]` and `change[1]`  or join them to a string with seperator you like `' / '.join(change)`, ...

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

link = 'https://robinhood.com/stocks/AAPL'
r = requests.get(link)
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

value = soup.select_one('h2 span[aria-label]')['aria-label']
change = list(soup.select_one('#sdp-price-chart-price-change span').stripped_strings)

print('Current stock price of '+link+': '+value+'\nTotal change today: '+' / '.join(change))
```

#### Output

```
Current stock price of https://robinhood.com/stocks/AAPL: $171.90
Total change today: -$1.12 / (-0.65%)
```